# why one should use .trigger() jquery function and when?

Tags: jquery

I was investigating about jQuery function `trigger()`. I got definition and all but I didn't understand why one should use this. Like e.g. given

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

This returns popup once page is load and when one click button with id "foo".

but this can also be done by just click() or just add

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

I didnt understand why and when i should use this and how exactly it works?

I have read about this from other resources but answers from here are more satisfactory.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `$('#someForm').trigger('submit');` seem something you'd be more likely to use? Or are you asking why you'd trigger a click event using `.trigger('click')` rather than `.click()`?

Comment: yes that what i was mean to why .trigger('click') , why not just .click.

Comment: But also .trigger('click') automatically show alert msg ?

Answer (score 2):

`.trigger()` is actually faster and it results in one less function.

Internally, the `.click()` method actually eventually uses `.trigger()`:

```
jQuery.fn.click = function (data, fn) {
    if (fn == null) {
        fn = data;
        data = null;
    }

     return arguments.length > 0 ? this.on("click", null, data, fn) : this.trigger("click");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

using this code

```
$('#foo').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

will just add a listener for the click and whenever you click the item , then only this alert will come , not automatically,

but if its your requirement based on some condition matched you want to show that alert and user is actually not clicking on the item then you can trigger it from your js

using this

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
```

now talking about `.click()` does nothing but calls the above function, so it will save you one function call binding and returning ....

so it is a technical slower then trigger but , it this call and returning minute delay matters to your project

Answer (score 0):

From a comment above:

> *"Why `.trigger('click')`, why not just `.click()`?"*

It is true that the following two lines have the same effect:

```
$('#foo').trigger('click');
$('#foo').click();
```

The latter is obviously easier to type, but as has already been pointed out it ends up calling `.trigger('click')` behind the scenes so it is less efficient at run time - though in many situations the difference won't matter at all.

However, **the other advantage of `.trigger()` is that it allows you to pass additional information to the event handler,** something you *can't* do by calling `.click()`. For example:

```
$('#foo').trigger('click', ['extra', 'info']);
```

This extra information is then available via parameters in your event handler:

```
$('#foo').on('click', function(event, param1, param2) {
  alert(param1 + "\n" + param2);
});
```

(Note that this example is pretty much the same as one in the [jQuery doco](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) where you got the code in the question. Did you read all of that doco page?)

Comment: Yeah, i have taken example from the same place